# Handling Asynchronous operations in Windows Phone7

Tags: windows-phone-7, asynchronous, mobile-application

I am developing a Windows Phone7 application in which I have two App bar buttons both when clicked makes Asynchronous calls to Web and Callbacks will be performed upon the Web response.

Now my problem is, if I click on one button and as the Async operation is going on in the background ans meanwhile if I click on another button both callbacks are executing one after the other, which is not good for obvious reasons. Could any one help me on how to handle this???

First I thought to disable other buttons when 1 Async operation is going. But it doesnt give good feel for user. So what will be the best way to handle this problem??

Comment: You are going to have to give us more information. Exactly how are you firing theses asynchronous operations? Having multiple, concurrent asynchronous operations is entirely possible. But how you do this depends very much on what you are doing.

Comment: @ColinE Yes multiple, concurrent asynchronous operations is entirely possible. But here in my case, both callbacks updates the same UI(view). If the View is not in visible state, then it can be updated in the background. I think I am not confusing you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Flag variable and check its value within the async call complete method. Based on your requirement you can choose to update or not update the view.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In that case, if I choose to go with the 2nd click and want to stop the 1st async call, is there a way to identify the (under-progress) async operations and to stop them.?

Comment: Per my limited knowledge there is no cancel property. We can always use the timeout limit to break after let us say a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same answer.

I have found the solution, If you initialize an object inside a constructor like this, you will get multiple loops when you call a service function:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
MovieServiceClient mov;

public MainPage()
{
mov = new MovieServiceClient(); //Don't do this.
InitializeComponent();

}
}
```

Avoid that.